# How to solve a $ay''(x) + (b-x)y'(x)+ c y(x) = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does anyone know if there exists an explicit solution to the following differential equation:

$a y'' + (b-x)y'+ c y = 0$

Here, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constants. The trivial solution is $y(x)=0$. I wonder if there is any nontrivial solution to that differential equation.

Comment: Solution by wolfram alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ay%27%27%2B%28b-x%29+y%27%2Bcy%3D0&x=0&y=0

Comment: There is. If you are not familiar with special functions it may seem strange though. Do you know how to solve ODE's via power series?

Comment: Yes, there are nontrivial solutions. This is a linear second order system; its solution space is two-dimensional. That the solutions are hypergeometric functions is a fact of life. Yes, they can be locally expressed as a power series, but it's not clear why one would want to do that.  @TylerHG

Comment: Sometimes, when learning differential equations for the first time, bringing up special functions can be a bit overwhelming. I was unaware of the OP's background so I was suggesting a power series solution just to help give some insight into solving a DE when the solutions are not known immediately. As spitting out solutions in terms of special functions doesn't really give a lot of insight.